# No FID in attribute table when creating a fishnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, vector-grid

I have a vector polygon and I want to create a 3 x 3 km fishnet over the polygon.

However, when I create the fishnet and check the attribute table of the new layer there is no FID column in the table.

Can anyone explain how to create a fishnet and retain the FID column?

Comment: Can you upload a screen shot of the problem? FID are usually just for Shapefiles and ObjectID's are for GeoDatabase FeatureClasses.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The vector polygon is a Shapefile Feature Class but when I create the fishnet the new layer is a GeoDatabase Feature Class. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: If your fishnet is being stored in a geodatabase it will never have an FID it gets an OBJECTID, essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way I can prevent my fishnet from being stored in a geodatabase and retain my feature class as a shapefile?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem when I create buffer around a point. Before I apply the buffer the attribute table of the point vector has an FID value but the layer created after the buffer is applied has an OID instead of an FID and this is creating a problem. Any help or suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the output goes into a shapefile (which has an FID), or into a geodatabase (which has an OID instead) depends on how you specify your Output Feature Class in the fishnet tool.

This will create a shapefile:

D:\Temp\test.shp

And this will create a file geodatabase feature class:

D:\Temp\MyFileGeodatabase.gdb\test

Comment: Perfect, that's the solution I was looking for